# Error message: "KHR/khrplatform.h" cannot be opened, but "khrplatform" does not exist anywhere within the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw, glad

I am trying to open a window in OpenGL. In Visual Studio, I set an include directory with all my header files, such as glfw3.h and glad.h. My include statements are properly formatted:

```
#include <glad/glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

There is an extra "glad/" because in the file explorer there is an extra glad folder. Another header file contained within the include folder is "khrplatform.h". This is the directory sequence:

> include/glad/KHR/khrplatform.h

Here is the code I wrote to open the window:

```
#include <glad/glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 


int main() {
glfwInit(); //initializes the openGL window

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); //This line and the next set the desired version of glfw (major.minor)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //sets openGL to the core profile (fewer functions)

return 0;
}
```

There is also a glad.c file in my visual studio project that is necessary for the window opening programming. The error message I get specifies the error as in the glad.c file. Here is the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenGL_SampleProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>glad.c
1>c:\users\david\documents\opengl\libs_include\include\glad\glad\glad.h(95): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'KHR/khrplatform.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "OpenGL_SampleProject.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

The problem is that the text "khrplatform.h" doesn't appear in glad.c at all. So I have no idea where the bug is originating from. Can someone with experience setting up and using OpenGL answer this for me?

Comment: Your error message says on line 95 of `c:\users\david\documents\opengl\libs_include\include\glad\glad\glad.h` you try to include `KHR/khrplatform.h`

Answer (score 2):

In glad.h, khrplatform.h gets included. The exact syntax used is:

```
    #include <KHR/khrplatform.h>
```

Because you added another glad folder, you setup your include directory one level too high. Which means glad.h should actually be referencing:

```
    #include <glad/KHR/khrplatform.h>
```

if your folder structure were to look like this:

-dependencies (set as include directory in Visual Studio)

----glad

-------glad

----------glad.h

-------KHR

----------khrplatform.h

You will have to change the include directory to this:

-dependencies

----glad (set as include directory in Visual Studio)

-------glad

----------glad.h

-------KHR

----------khrplatform.h

Because that would make the `<KHR/khrplatform.h>` in glad.h correct.

You could also just get rid of that extra glad folder, but if you really want to keep it you would have to change your include directories in visual studio.

The specific setting you would change can be found like this:

Rightclick the project name in the solution explorer -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General

Under the setting "Additional Include Directories", you have to change the path to the one mentioned above.

Alternatively you can change the glad.h file, but I don't recommend it. As you might update glad at some point in the future, which will mean you will have to manually change that line of code again.